# Running an exe file just by giving it's name to cmd

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, exe

I am running an exe file created with python from the powershell.

I am running it by doing

```
& C\users\rey\.....\main.exe
```

what I want to is to just pass the main.exe to the command prompt to run the exe file but when I do that now I get the error that:

> "main.exe is not recognized as a cmdlet function, function, script type ...."

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The main.exe file must be 1) in a directory included in the $PATH variable or 2) must be in the current working directory and invoked with `& ".\main.exe"`. The PowerShell command console does not inherently recognize the current directory for executable files as do `cmd.exe` and `command.com`.

Comment: It just has to be in the `Path` System environment variable to be able to call it directly. Don't put the full name to the file, just the path to where the file resides in.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the path of the file or the path of the folder containing the file in system environment variables. Then you can use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Either powershell or cmd need to know the complete path to your file, but if you don't want to repeatedly type that long `& C:\users\rey\.....\folder\main.exe` every time, you could set your powershell to work from your folder with:

```
cd C:\users\rey\.....\folder\
```

Then call the .exe with `.\main.exe`

Comment: well the idea is to not pass the path just the main.exe

Comment: Well, @NateR, if you just pass the pure name, PowerShell somehow needs to know where to search for it…